# Scroll in sencha architect

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-architect

I'm very new with Sencha Architect and I  wanted to know how, when the content is bigger than the screen, I can scroll down to see the content, I've tried to put scrollable on "vertical" in the main panel but that does't seem to do anything. Right now the containers are just pushed out of the screen and I can't scroll to them.

I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of that problem? Is the issue inside the Architect window or in the output app in the web browser?

Comment: The problem is already resolved, but thanks for your response!